# How can I wrap text to the new line properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to wrap my text to the new line when no space is available. but I have a problem.

I have written the following code:

```
 return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Wrap(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8,right: 8),
              child: Text('HelllOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO everyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Above code returns following image:

[image]

As you can see, "everyyyy.." word, wrapped to the next line completely. I want to create something like the following images:

[image]

[image]

Please help me, I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Remove space before `every`, try to use `maxLines` for `Text`, set `width` for `Container`.

Comment: thanks. text will be dynamic and i can't define rules for that. other things you said did not work

Comment: So if text is dynamic how do you expect that it will be wrapped somehiw tricky? Flutter uses its own algo for wrapping. If you don't like it, use your own, calc symbols, width. There is an answer in stackoverflow hiw to calc width of `Text` widget.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please check accepted answer. that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for your `Text` Widget:

```
Text('HelllOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO everyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'.replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0')),
```